# How to copy cell in EEPPlus v4.0.4 which contains Validationlist?

Tags: c#, epplus

I have a Cell containing a Validationlist and I would like to copy this to the new inserted row below.

Unfortunately this:

```
ExcelRange rgdropdowndesresp = Sheet.Cells[17, 8];

for (int i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
{
    rgdropdowndesresp.Copy(Sheet.Cells[17 + i, 8]);
}
```

just copies the selected text, not the Validationlist itself.

Is there maybe another way?

Comment: I think by drop down, you mean a validation list? These lists require a very special handling by using `sheet.DataValidations`.

Comment: @fero yep, sorry, been to long in windows forms ;)

Comment: So as I said, you have to use the `DataValidations` property to add another validation list for the copied cell or recreate the original validation list to include the new cell. There is no other option AFAIK.

Comment: @fero  `sheet.DataValidations` works for me partially, as i have few columns with data validation also with Offset function and those columns are not coming in worksheet DataValidations list.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code for the `Copy` command it does nothing with data validations.  So you would have to do it yourself like @fero said.  Something like this should do it:

```
//Test if the cell A1 has a validation list
var sourceDv = worksheet.DataValidations["A1"];
if (sourceDv != null)
{
    //Test for each type
    if (sourceVal.ValidationType.Type == eDataValidationType.List)
    {
        var destCell = worksheet.Cells["A10"];
        var destVal = worksheet.DataValidations.AddListValidation(destCell.Address);
        destVal.Formula.ExcelFormula = sourceVal.Formula.ExcelFormula;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(sourceVal.ValidationType.Type.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: this works for me partially, as i have few columns with data validation also with Offset function and those columns are not coming in worksheet.DataValidations list.